# Req.body with postman UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'req.body' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

I'm trying to do a put request with POSTMAN to my backend and its seem to be a problem I believe that's stupid but I just don't find it. It says:"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'req.body' as it is undefined."

```js
router.put("/todos/", async (req, res, next) => {
  const { id, content } = req.body;
  try {
    const todo = (DUMMY_PLACES = {
      ...state,
      allIds: [...state.allIds, id],
      byIds: {
        ...state.byIds,
        [id]: {
          content,
          completed: false,
        },
      },
    });
    return success(res, todo);
  } catch (err) {
    next({ status: 400, message: "failed to update todo" });
  }
});
```

The request in Postman:

```js
{
    "id": 6,
    "content": "asd"
  }
```

How the DUMMYDB Looks like

```js
const DUMMY_PLACES = [
  {
    todos: {
      allIds: [1, 2, 3, 4],
      byIds: {
        "1": {
          content: "test1",
          completed: false,
        },
        "2": {
          content: "test2",
          completed: false,
        },
        "3": {
          content: "test3\\",
          completed: false,
        },
        "4": {
          content: "test4",
          completed: false,
        },
      },
    },
    visibilityFilter: "all",
  },
];
```

Comment: Have you added `app.use(express.json())` when configuring the application? Or just try to `log` the `req.body` and see what it has.

Comment: Im checking i will tell you in 5 minutes

Comment: Yes i used app.use(express.json()), and i cant arrived to console.log(req.body) its sending an error before

Comment: Ok. I am not able to figure out what could be causing the issue. Will it be possible for you to add more code in the question section with appropriate file names?

Comment: I got it, thank my friend.

Comment: But do you know how can i update my DUMMY_PLACE  array, to add a new number in allIds,byIds?

Comment: because the solution that I wrote is not even logic.